# Return a specific value from an API

Tags: python

I use this script to get crypto prices:

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
import json

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
response = cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='usd')
print(response)

token = response.get('bitcoin','')
print(token)
```

and the output returned is:

**{'bitcoin': {'usd': 60302}}**

**{'usd': 60302}**

How can I get just the value 60302 instead of the full column?

Comment: `token['bitcoin']['usd']` try this

Comment: @mhhabib I updated to **print(token['bitcoin']['usd'])** but I get **KeyError: 'bitcoin'**

Answer (score 1):

It's return a Dictionary, and the best way to parse a dictionary is as follows:

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
import json

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
response = cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='usd')
print(response) #remove this to get rid of all of the other text and just return usd

token = response.get('bitcoin','')
print(token['usd']) # Just put the name of the key 'usd' here!
```

If you wanted it to tell you what cryptocoin:

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
import json

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
response = cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='usd')


token = response.get('bitcoin','')
print("Bitcoin price: ", token['usd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is a nested dictionary. So you have the first one, named `Bitcoin` and inside it you have another dictionary named `usd`. So this is how your data looks like:

```
{
    'Bitcoin': {
        'USD': '60320'
    }
}
```

Since you know the name of the keys, you can access these directly by typing like this: `token['bitcoin']['usd']`